# Return complete array from Promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I have a function that returns JSON objects using `hnews.getById(id)`. I then push each story returned in the promise to an array. I'm having trouble figuring out how I'd then get the complete array. Do I need to use another promise?

```
function updateTopStories() {
    var storiesArr = [];

    hnews.getIdsInCategory('topstories', 60)
    .then(function(ids) {
        ids.forEach(function(id) {
            hnews.getById(id).then(function(story) {
                console.log(story);
                storiesArr.push(story);
            });
        });
    });

    return storiesArr;
}

var stories = updateTopStories();
console.log(stories); // Empty array
```

EDIT: I need to return `storiesArr` from `updateTopStories();`

Comment: Can you paste a sample output that you get and expected output

Comment: `hnews.getById(id)` returns a promise or JSON array ?

Comment: @Agalo `hnews.getById(id)` returns a JSON object

Comment: @MiteshPant the array is empty. My expected output would be an array containing objects for each story.

Comment: I assume you need to return `storiesArr` from `updateTopStories()`. Then please update your question (find the `edit` button below your post). In that case, yes, you need a `Promise` to be returned from `updateTopStories()`. See [MDN on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). In the example provided there, you'd need to return the `Promise` (instead of storing it as `p1`).

Comment: @Agalo `getIdsInCategory` returns an array of ids [1, 2, 3,] from there I want to look up information about each id in the array. I do this by calling `getById(id)` which returns a json object containing the story's info. I would ideally like to push each story object to one big array where I can send it as a response to the user using NodeJS.

Comment: @try-catch-finally Editing. Thank you.

Comment: Going to close this thread.

Comment: @ColeRoberts remember you can't magically go from async to sync.  I know you want to return an array but you are better of returning a Promise containing that array as everything up to that point is async.  Your array will always be empty because it will return before the async code has ever had a chance to populate.  See my solution below

Comment: @DeezCashews much appreciated. I'll make note of that and follow your solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are invoking multiple async processes here.  A common way of handling this is to map your array of ids to an array of Promises which all have to resolve before returning.  See if this works for you.

```
function updateTopStories() {

    return hnews.getIdsInCategory('topstories', 60).then(function(ids) {
        var promises = ids.map(function(id) {
            return hnews.getById(id);
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    });
}

updateTopStories().then(function(stories) {
    console.log(stories);
});
```

Comment: As the OP wrote, "`hnews.getById(id)` returns a JSON object", not Promises.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I saw that in the comment but obviously his original code is using `hnew.getById(id).then` which would lead one to believe its a Promise.  Probably shouldn't have asked if it was or not in first place ;)

Comment: @try-catch-finally Updated. Sorry.

Comment: @ColeRoberts edited, sorry forgot a return statement from first call to hnews before.

Comment: @DeezCashews worked like a charm. Thank you very much. Marking your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure as I am not able to try this, but looks like you have scoping problem here, try to do this.

```
     function updateTopStories() {
        var tempStoriesArr = [];

        hnews.getIdsInCategory('topstories', 60)
        .then(function(ids) {
            ids.forEach(function(id) {
                hnews.getById(id).then(function(story) {
                    console.log(story);
                    tempStoriesArr.push(story);
                });
            });
        });
        return tempStoriesArr;
    }

    var StoriesArr = updateTopStories();
    console.log(StoriesArr);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but in this case the array is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could reconstruct your response from each call as:

```
function updateTopStories() {
    var storiesArr = {};

    hnews.getIdsInCategory('topstories', 60)
    .then(function(ids) {
        ids.forEach(function(id) {
            storiesArr[id] = [];
            hnews.getById(id).then(function(story) {
                console.log(story);
                storiesArr[id].push(story);
            });
        });
    });
    return storiesArr;
}

updateTopStories();
```

Here you are initializing each story for a particular id group which is an array and then you can retrieve each story based on the id's.

Comment: The object is still empty. Is there any other reason you can see why that would be happening?

Comment: Could you add a fiddle of your working code? That would help.

Comment: Please ask for clarification of the question before quickly answering - IMO this question is not clear enough at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise and return something from within the "then" block if you want to transform it.
You can use Array.prototype.map to transform an array.

```
function updateTopStories() {
  return hnews.getIdsInCategory('topstories', 60)
    .then(function(ids) {
      return ids.map(function(id) {
        return hnews.getById(id).then(function(story) {
            console.log(story);
            return story;
        });
    });
  });
}

updateTopStories().then(function(arr) {
  arr.foreach(function(s) {
    console.log('Story:', s);
  });
});
```

Comment: There's no `storiesArr` declared. This code would fail. `getById()` returns no Promise either as the OP wrote in his 1st sentence.

Comment: @bsyk incorrectly stated that it was returning objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the idea:

```
function return_promise_array(para1):Promise<any>{
   return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{
      var result=[];
      var level1=await get_promise_array();
      var process=[];
      for(var i=0;i<level1.length;i++){
        //after process the item, write the item result into result array 
        process.push(process_promise_item(level1[i],result));
      }
      //no way to run promise in for loop, 
      //but you can create promise function and add it into array,
      //then run it in Promise.all() 
      await Promise.all(process);  
      resolve(result);
   });
}
var result=[];
result=await return_promise_array(para1); //can return as array without error.
```