# Return value is not output although it can be output in fconsole.log in firestore + vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Return value is not output although it can be output in console.log
I used [created] and [mounted] in vue.js But value is undefind

I examined the official document, but can not you return many console.log descriptions?

```
-----vue.js
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>{{ this.data }}</h2>
        <router-link to="/inviteform">InviteForm</router-link>
    </div>
</template>



<script>
import Firebase from '@/api/firebase/firebase'
import Firestore from '@/api/firebase/firestore'
export default {
    name: 'InvitePage',
    data(){
      return {
          email: this.$route.params.id,
          data: ""
      }
    },
    computed:{
        inviteData(){
            Firestore.getInviteData(this.$route.params.id)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.data = Firestore.getInviteData(this.$route.params.id)
        console.log("mounted",this)
    },
    created: function(){
        this.data = Firestore.getInviteData(this.$route.params.id)
        console.log("cretated",this.data)
    },
    methods: {
        getInviteData(){
        Firestore.getInviteData(this.$route.params.id)
        }
    }
}



----firestore.js
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import {store} from '@/store/'
import router from '@/router'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'



const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'exercise-vue')
const firestore = firebaseApp.firestore();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);



export default {
    getInviteData(uid){
        let array = []
        firestore.collection("invite").doc(uid).get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data())
                array.push(doc.data().date);
                console.log("Document arraydata:", array[0])
                return array[0]
            } else {
              // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
              console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
}
```

console.log is working properly
I examined the official document, but can not you return many console.log descriptions?

Comment: `getInviteData` is not returning anything. If you would return `firestore.collection(....` then it would return a *promise*. You need to look into how to deal with promises and asynchrony. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605745/return-complete-array-from-promise) for inspiration.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "return many console.log descriptions"? Do you mean that you want to get several documents from the "invite" Firestore collection?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec  yes, now it can be output in console.log ,　I wanna get [Return value ] as output in console.log

Comment: Sorry, you have to explain more clearly what you really expect and what you already get. If you seek for help on Stack Overflow you need to be extremely clear, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which gives more details. In your case, it is not clear what is [Return value ]  and by which console.log() you get it. I more or less understand that you may want to print the values of the fields of one document: you should also add a printscreen of your Firestore database.

Comment: Also, you don't need to repeat `this.data = Firestore.getInviteData(this.$route.params.id)` everywhere in your Vue.js component. Having it only once is usually sufficient: either in the `created` life cycle hook if you want to load data when you open the component, or in a `method` if you want to trigger the load via, e.g. a button.